# How to find the content of String Constant Pool in Java?

Tags: java, string, pool

Is there a way to check if a string is already available in String Constant Pool ?

A related question to same could be:

```
String s = "Hello" + "World";
```

How many Strings will be created in the Constant Pool for this statement: 1 or 3?

As per javap command "javap -c -verbose" I can print the Constatnt pool table and check the String constants created. I found that only 1 String is created for String s = "Hello" + "World"; statement. Is there a way to programmatically know the contents of String Constant Pool.

For below code:

```
String s = "0";
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    s = s + i;
}
```

I know there will be total 10 String objects will be created, only the last one "0123456789" will be referenced by s. Others will be left without any reference. How can I see or check the existence of those strings e.g. "01" in String constant pool?

Comment: can you show how much you have done research?

Comment: As per javap command "javap -c -verbose" I can print the Constatnt pool table and check the String constants created. I found the answer is 1 String is created for  String s = "Hello" + "World"; statement. Thanks. Please Let me know if there is way to programmatically know the contents of String Constant Pool.

Comment: please add these explanations to your post

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access the String intern pool.

As per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29 String intern pool is:

**A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained `privately` by the class String.**

However String objects can be added to this pool using String's `intern()` method.

`java.lang.String.intern()` returns an interned String, that is, one that has an entry in the global String pool. If the String is not already in the global String pool, then it will be added.

Programmatically you can follow this approach:

**1.Declare Set StringConstantPool = new HashSet();**

**2.call String.intern()**

**3.Add returned String value into this pool StringConstantPool**

only one string will be created HelloWord in constant pool